# ActiveRecord from an existing PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, scaffolding

I've been looking all around the web and i couldnt found a concrete solution to my issue, i want to **create a model Client that has an existing table clients in the PostgreSQL** server.

Im using **rails 4**, and i've been trying to create the model Client and the controller Clients like this:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  scaffold:client
end
```

But when calling localhost:3000/clients/new a **warning of pending migrations appear**. It has no sense making the migration if the database and table are already there with information, **how can i do to notice rails that the migrations have to be ignored?**

**UPDATE:**

I have **generated a model and a controller in rails 4**,Client and ClientsController, and **configure the database.yml** with the postgres adapater and the database name, and i **want that rails get the table attributes from the clients table and generate the forms and all the scaffolding CRUD operations.** I've seen in the web some similar solutions but with mysql database and i think with rails 3...

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Did you run a generator to create the model and controller? If so, did it also create a migration file for you under `db/migrate`?

Delete the migration file and Rails should stop complaining about pending migrations.

If you have other migrations that are pending, run `rake db:migrate` to run them.

Comment: yes i run a generator to create the model and controller for Client and the migrations are generated, i will try remove the migration file, otherwise the form will keep all the attributes in the postgreSQL database?

Comment: in fact i try removing the migrations file and the pending migrations dissapear, but the new Client form does not present the attributes in the database...